# Supremum of norm of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I found This problem and solution on maths stack exchange and i was unable to understand the last step of this solution in which an inequality is written. Question is that Let A be an $n \times n$ self adjoint matrix with eigenvalues $ \lambda_1,..., \lambda_n$. Let $||X||_2= \sqrt {|x_1|^2 +...+|x_n|^2}$ for $X= (x_1,...,x_n)\in \Bbb C^n$. If $p(A)= a_0I+ a_1A+\cdots+a_nA^n$. Then prove that $sup_{||x||_2=1} ||p(A)x||_2$ = max{$a_0+a_1\lambda_j +\cdots+a_n\lambda_j^n|: 1\le j\le n$}. I know that eigenvalues of self adjoint matrix are always real. 
 $p(A)x= a_0x + a_1Ax+\cdots+a_n A^n x$  Then i found it's solution as A key fact about selfadjoint matrices:

> Eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal

Using this repeatedly, one quickly shows that $A$ admits an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. Let $V$ be the unitary that makes the change of basis from the canonical basis to $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$. The key observation is that the set of all $x$ such that $\|x\|=1$ is the same as the set of all $x$ such that $\|Vx\|=1$. So we may assume that  $x=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\,v_j$.

Then any $x$ can be written 
$$
x=\sum_{j=1}^n x_jv_j,
$$
and
$$\tag{1}
p(A)x=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\,p(A)v_j
$$
It is easy to check that 
$$\tag{2}
p(A)v_j=p(\lambda_j)v_j.
$$
So 
$$
p(A)x=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j\,p(\lambda_j)v_j,
$$
and, since $\sum_{j=1}^n|x_j|^2=1$,
$$
\|p(A)x\|=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n |x_jp(\lambda_j)|^2\right)^{1/2}\leq\max\{|p(\lambda_j)|:\ 1\leq j\leq n\}.
$$
My doubt is that how last inequality was written? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $|b_i| \leq M$ for all $i$ then $\sum |a_ib_i|^{2} \leq \sum |a_i|^{2}M^{2}$. Take square roots now.

[$a_i=x_i,b_i=p(\lambda_i)$ and $M=\max \{|p(\lambda_i)|: 1 \leq i \leq n\}$].

Comment: How maximum came into inequality

Comment: Do you agree that $|p(\lambda_i)| \leq M$?

Comment: yes sir. i thought it in other direction. I thought that set of all vectors with norm 1 is a compact subspace then i defined a map from this set to ||p(A)x|| and it is a continuous function but stuck here how to proceed further